# having problems with ensemble stacking 3 deep learning models

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

Trying to implement an ensemble stacking model using densenet121 and inceptionv3 as base models
and resnet50 as the meta model for a deepfake image detection graduation project.
Encountering problems with shapes of the models and their predictions.
Using saved predictions from the dataset and a loaded fine-tuned resnet50.

It's a binary classification problem.the error:

```
model.fit(
    concat,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=val_generator
)
WARNING:tensorflow:Keras is training/fitting/evaluating on array-like data. Keras may not be optimized for this format, so if your input data format is supported by TensorFlow I/O (https://github.com/tensorflow/io) we recommend using that to load a Dataset instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[95], line 1
    model.fit(

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70 in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py:259 in <genexpr>
    int(i.shape[0]) for i in tf.nest.flatten(inputs)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'
```

```
# Import the necessary libraries
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape
import tensorflow_io as tfio

# Define the paths to the directories of images
train_dir = 'D:/140k dataset/real_vs_fake/real-vs-fake/train'
val_dir = 'D:/140k dataset/real_vs_fake/real-vs-fake/valid'
test_dir = 'D:/140k dataset/real_vs_fake/real-vs-fake/test'

# Define the batch size and the image size
batch_size = 32
image_size = (224, 224)

# Create an image data generator for data augmentation and normalization
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=10,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True
)

# Create a train generator that yields batches of images and labels
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'
)

# Create a validation generator that yields batches of images and labels
val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'
)

# Create a test generator that yields batches of images and labels
test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'
)

# Load the predictions from your PC
inceptionv3_pred = np.load('C:/Users/A.N/inceptionpredictions.npz')['inception']
densenet121_pred = np.load('C:/Users/A.N/densnetpredictions.npz')['densenet']


# Concatenate the predictions
concat = Concatenate()([inceptionv3_pred, densenet121_pred])

# Convert the KerasTensor to a numpy array
concat = np.array(concat)

# Save the concatenated predictions as a numpy file
np.savez('concat.npz', concat)
# Load the meta model from your PC
meta_model = load_model('D:/trained_models/resnet50/resnet_model.h5')

# Freeze the meta model
meta_model.trainable = False

# Concatenate the predictions
concat = Concatenate()([inceptionv3_pred, densenet121_pred])

concat = (inceptionv3_pred + densenet121_pred) / 2.0


# Reshape the predictions to match the input shape of the meta model
#concat = Reshape((128, 128, 3))(concat)
concat = Input(shape=( 128,128,3)) 
concat.shape

# Save the concatenated predictions as a numpy file


# Get the output from the meta model
output = meta_model(concat)

# Add a final dense layer for classification
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(output)

# Create the final model
model = Model(inputs=concat, outputs=output)

# Compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Print the model summary
model.summary()


# Fit the model on the concatenated predictions
model.fit(
    concat,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=val_generator
)

# Evaluate the model on the test generator
model.evaluate(test_generator)
```

Comment: First, `concat` is an array of predictions, then with `concat = Input(shape=( 128,128,3))` it becomes in input layer without any data. What do you expect it to be when you hand it to `model.fit`?

Comment: yea you are correct i thought i was reshaping the predictions since the predictions output are (20000, 4), and the model input shape is (None, 128, 128, 3) any idea what could be done here?